# object dictionary mean value

Tags: excel, vba

I have weather data for daily hour for many month as picture. I try to calculate daily hour mean value for using Excel VBA object dictionary. the code as below:

my question. why I miss first row value. please refer picture. the first hour value are 1026.8 , 1026.8 1027 , 1027. the mean value is #1026.9#. After change value. I am sure. first 1026.8 value is missing.

No idea why. Check VBA locals expression also fine.

[image]

```
Sub Qi_Ya_code()

Dim columnA As Range
Dim columnB As Range
Dim columnC As Range
Dim columnAB As Range


Set columnA = Sheet1.Range("A:A")
Set columnB = Sheet1.Range("B:B")
Set columnC = Sheet1.Range("C:C")
Set columnAB = Sheet1.Range("AB:AB")

    Dim rownumt As Integer
    Dim rownumt1 As Integer
    Dim Cell_Row As Range
    Dim Cell_Row1 As Range

Dim i&, j&
Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
Set d1 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

Mdata_start = Format(Application.WorksheetFunction.EDate(Me.ComboBox1 & "/" & Me.ComboBox2 & "/" & Me.ComboBox3, 0), "MM/DD/YYYY")
Mdata_end = Format(Application.WorksheetFunction.EDate(Me.ComboBox4 & "/" & Me.ComboBox5 & "/" & Me.ComboBox6, 0), "MM/DD/YYYY")



Set Cell_Row = columnA.Find(Mdata_start, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)

rownumt = Cell_Row.Row

Set Cell_Row1 = columnA.Find(Mdata_end, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)

rownumt1 = Cell_Row1.Row


With Worksheets("Sheet1")


 arr = .Range("A" & rownumt - 1, "AY" & rownumt1)
 
 For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
   If Not d.exists(arr(i, 1)) Then
     Set d(arr(i, 1)) = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
   Else
     d(arr(i, 1))(arr(i, 2)) = d(arr(i, 1))(arr(i, 2)) + arr(i, 11)
     d1(arr(i, 1) & "+" & arr(i, 2)) = d1(arr(i, 1) & "+" & arr(i, 2)) + 1
   End If
Next

 r = 2: l = 1
 For Each aa In d.keys
   For Each bb In d(aa).keys
      s = d(aa).Count - 1
      ss = d1(aa & "+" & bb)
     Sheet3.Cells(r, l) = aa
     Sheet3.Cells(r, l + 1) = bb
     Sheet3.Cells(r, l + 2) = d(aa)(bb) / ss
     
      r = r + 1
     
  Next

Next

End With
 
End Sub
```

please help check code. What's going on???//

Answer (score 1):

When a new key is found, a new Dictionary is created but no value is set.

```
        If Not d.exists(arr(i, 1)) Then
            Set d(arr(i, 1)) = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        Else
            d(arr(i, 1))(arr(i, 2)) = d(arr(i, 1))(arr(i, 2)) + arr(i, 11)
            d1(arr(i, 1) & "+" & arr(i, 2)) = d1(arr(i, 1) & "+" & arr(i, 2)) + 1
        End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this a little more simply:

```
    '...
    '...
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        k = arr(i, 1) & "|" & arr(i, 2)               'composite key
        If Not d.exists(k) Then d.Add kd, Array(0, 0) 'new date+hour?
        tmp = d(k)    'can't work on an array inside a dictionary
        tmp(0) = tmp(0) + arr(i, 11) 'sum
        tmp(1) = tmp(1) + 1          'count
        d(k) = tmp    'update array
    Next

    ReDim arrOut(1 To d.Count, 1 To 3) 'size output array
    r = 1
    For Each k In d.keys
        arr = Split(k, "|")
        tmp = d(k)
        arrOut(r, 1) = arr(0)
        arrOut(r, 2) = arr(1)
        arrOut(r, 3) = tmp(0) / tmp(1)
        r = r + 1
    Next
    Sheet3.Cells(2, 1).Resize(d.Count, 3).Value = arrOut
```

Comment: Sorry. can not work at  " tmp(0) = tmp(0) + arr(i, 11) 'sum " .  show "Run time error "13" " Type mismatch.

Comment: Maybe `arr(i, 11)` is not numeric?  What is the value when it errors?